# pandas python how to consider number of rows with another defined number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, large-data

I have 1_000_000 rows of data that only 5_000 of them are not zero and rest of the rows are 0. Som I just added 5000 rows to my `Dataframe`. Now let me know is there any possible command in pandas to set the number of rows equal to 1_000_000 to do calculations (like mean or std or ...) considering the correct number of the rows?

Comment: Is it a problem to have 1_000_000 rows?

Comment: Can you please give an example of your DataFrame, let's say with 20 rows, 4 of which are non-zero. This depends on hwo the data is organized